# How to fix "Unknown argument 'slug' " in gatsbyjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am currently trying to create a blog site using gatsbyjs, and would like my blog posts to have their pages created for them programmatically.

I followed the steps in the tutorials section of the official documentation, but instead of creating the pages from a markdown file, I am pulling data from the contentful CMS. I keep on hitting this block whenever I run my code.

gatsby-node.js

```
const path= require('path')

exports.createPages=({graphql,actions})=>{
const {createPage}=actions

const blogPost= path.resolve('./src/components/blogComponents/blog-post.js')
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    graphql(`
    {
        allContentfulBlog{
            edges{
              node{
                slug
              }
            }
          }
    }
`).then(results=>{
    // console.log(results)
    if(results.error){
        reject(results.error)
    }
      // create blog post pages
const posts=results.data.allContentfulBlog.edges

posts.forEach((post,index)=>{
    console.log(`showing slugs: ${post.node.slug}`)

   createPage({
        path:post.node.slug,
        component:blogPost ,
        context:{

            slug:post.node.slug,

        } 
    })

    })
}).then(resolve)
}) 
}
```

blog-post.js

```
   import React from 'react'
   import { graphql} from 'gatsby'


  const blogPost=({data})=>{
return (
    <div>
        new page created
    </div>
)
 }

 export default blogPost
 export const pageQuery= graphql`
  query ($slug: String!){
     allContentfulBlog (slug:{eq: $slug }) {
      edges{
      node{
       content{
           content
       }
      }
    }
  }
 }
 `
```

I expected the blog-post.js file to receive all appropriate variables, but instead, it kept on throwing the "unknown argument 'slug' " error while making reference to the blog-post.js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `blog-post.js`, it looks like you might have been filtering the posts incorrectly; either do this:

```
 export const pageQuery= graphql`
  query ($slug: String!){

-    allContentfulBlog (slug:{eq: $slug }) {

+    allContentfulBlog (filter: { slug: { eq: $slug } })

      edges {
        node {
         content {
           content
         }
        }
      }
    }
   }
 `
```

Or this:

```
 export const pageQuery= graphql`
  query ($slug: String!){

-    allContentfulBlog (slug:{eq: $slug }) {

+    ContentfulBlog (slug:{eq: $slug }) {

     content {
       content
     }
    }
   }
 `
```

Comment: Thank you very much derek, i just tried it and it worked like a charm. I read somewhere that it’s better to use the “contenfulBlog” every without the prefixed *all as it is much easier to deconstruct.

Comment: @mujeexminiminer glad it helped! I made some mistake in the Contentful example, will edit... I also prefer using just `ContentfulBlog`, for the same reason you mentioned.

Comment: Great! Now that i have your attention Derek, please could you guide or point me to any article on how to render rich-text? The rich-text transformer plugin appears to have been deprecated. I have been searching for a way out ever since.

Comment: @mujeexminiminer is it rich text for contentful? have you read this one? https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/

Comment: Yes it is for Contentful. No, I don’t think i did! I will read through and see what i can get. Thanks a lot man!